# Downloading an image in Python does not properly display it

Tags: python, image

I am using PyCharm in order to download an image from a fixed URL
This is the code I'm using in order to do it:

```
import urllib.request 
import random 

def download_web_image(url): 
    name=random.randrange(0,1000) 
    fullname=str(name)+".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,fullname)

download_web_image('imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/626x626q90/673/MT82dR.jpg')
```

This is what happens when I double click the downloaded image:
[image]

But as you see the image is already downloaded in the Python directory and it is a proper image:

What do I have to do in order for the image to be properly displayed in Pycharm?

Comment: My code :          import urllib.request
import random
def download_web_image(url):
    name=random.randrange(0,1000)
    fullname=str(name)+".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,fullname)
download_web_image('http://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/626x626q90/673/MT82dR.jpg')

Comment: Can you sucessfully open the image out of PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the fact that the image was downloaded using Python. You will see the same behaviour if you copy an image into your project folder. You can fix it by telling PyCharm about which file types should be displayed as images.

In **Settings** (File->Settings on Windows) expand **Editor** then select **File Types**

Choose **Image** from the list of **Regognized File Types** (scroll down...) then make sure that **Registered Patterns** contains all the file types you want to be displayed as images. If `*.jpg` is not listed there, add it using the green `+` on the right.

[image: Settings]